# How to limit frame rate in Blender?

Tags: system, frame-rate

Even when nothing is happening on screen my graphics card is still whirring away. Where can I limit the frame rate in Blender to stop consuming so much unnecessary power please?

Comment: Unless you're running an animation or rendering an image Blender will not be causing your graphics card fan to run. Can you add an image of your Blender window when this is happening? Use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu then edit your question here and add the image.

Comment: When your graphics card needs to load whatever it needs to show the GUI and viewport: all that needs to be kept in memory. That's a GPU usage even if you literally go away for five minutes. And there is also the rest of your system and other apps to handle. Though whether it makes your GPU "whirring away" also depends on your hardware. Mine really needs a significant Cycles viewport render or a full frame render to start making noises, but a few years ago my hardware would have been busy just by booting the system.